# Remove all non-black pixels to white using R (Magick)

Tags: r, rmagick

I have a png file that I want to convert non-black pixels to white. This is pre-processing for OCR. How could I easily do that in R? Specifically, I would like to use the Magick library. Thanks!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data (in this case, that might mean an image) and all necessary code

Comment: You're looking for `magick::image_threshold`